Access to docker volume with intellij
I mounted the volume in the container. project perfectly works but i can't edit my code.
I tried to open the project through the below route with an intellij Ultimate, but the alarm keeps popping up.
\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\project_data\_data\proejctApp

I'm currently using docker desktop on Windows 10 Pro and the container works with Ubuntu 22.04.
How can I edit files inside a volume right through intellij?

You generally don't: Docker is designed so that the container content is isolated from the host system, and named volumes are designed as opaque storage that the host system can't directly access.  I tend to recommend not forcing Docker into your development setup, even if you'll eventually deploy in containers; use host tools that don't introduce these complexities.

(When you created the container, did you mean to use a bind mount instead of a named volume?  That will inject files from your host system into the container, and you can directly edit them there.  Note that I've seen several SO reports of this not working reliably, it can be slow on Windows in some circumstances, your IDE still can't directly use the tools in the container, and when you go to deploy you've never actually run the container image you've built this way.)

Please inline your image/screenshot. External resources can get lost and then the question remains incomplete.

@Antares I'd love to, but it's need 10 reputations.

Holy cow, StackOverflow and its reputations... didn't know about that limit. Thank you for reporting back! I have inlined the image for you :)
A hint for you: If you register with another StackExchange site (for example SuperUser or HomeImprovement), I think it will award you with +100 rep for that.
